# Find time optimal solution for a system following a trajectory using DIDO

Tags: matlab, control-theory, dido

I am using DIDO in MATLAB and I am experimenting on a triple integral system. I managed to find a time-optimal solution for a stable (independent of time) control target. Can I do the same for a time-dependent control target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After communicating with the DIDO distributors, they informed me that it is possible to do that!